# How has Twelver Shia evolved through the past 14 centuries, particularly during the Safavid era?

Tags: history, shiism

Derived from [this Question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7062/584) and [this Answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/7086/584) is a question about the history of the Twelver Shia branch of Islam. Would you please notify in short how did this branch evolved through the ages with focus concentrated around the Safavid era? The main points that are considered to exist in an accepted answer are these:

1. The main events that largely helped spreading this perspective (a list of events with references given for each can be very helpful, but only the main events please)
2. Does this claim that Safavid Empire in Persia was the main reason for the Twelver Shi'ism becoming the mainstream Shi'a sect has anything to do with reality?

Comment: Good question but it needs too long answer like a book, much more than what can be written here

Comment: @Ali, keeping the answer as short as possible should be enough, only tracking qualitatively how it evolved may suffice. You can start that with the fact that after the holy prophet --peace be upon him-- passed away Shia started to evolve from 3 or 5 or 7, then was branched and evolved, until Imam Baqir and Imam Sadiq --peace be upon them-- who had as many as thousands of students, not all of them Shia of them but caused in intensive spread of their ideas, then Imam Redha --peace be upon him-- coming to Iran, then the 9th, 10th, 11th Imam sending representatives to all over the Islamic land ...

Comment: This is question is too broad and contains off-topic question which might be better suited at [history.se]. The question needs to be spread across multiple questions.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, history of islam can equivalently belong to a history branch and to a Islamic branch in my opinion. However, I accept that the question is somewhat broad in scope, although it is almost focused on the history of the growth of Shi'ism in the Safavid era.

Comment: @owari Well, certainly history of Islam should be on-topic, but this question focuses on how a particular sect of muslims have spread/evolved (see the difference?). About the second point, this site it about Islam, percentage of follower is certainly off-topic. The third point is on-topic on [history.se] and certainly not here (not about Islam). See the question's good but it's the on-topicness and breadth of it that is concerning. Take it to [meta] if you want it discussed. Related question http://history.stackexchange.com/q/2913.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, now I see your point better, let me edit the question.

Comment: brother see this links:http://www.porseman.org/showarticle.aspx?id=1122   and if you need more:  http://www.al-islam.org/shiite-encyclopedia-ahlul-bayt-dilp-team    and this:  http://shiastudies.net/article/english/Article.php?id=2590

Comment: @FatemehBaqeri, thanks for the references, could you please also compile an answer out of them here?

Comment: answer to what? can you ask a definite question, me to answer that?

Comment: @FatemehBaqeri, an answer to the question below which you have first commented and brought three links as for references. The question is already definite in my mind, if you think it is not then feel free to revise it. Thank you.

Comment: I found two sites (in Farsi) which could be profitable for you. (of course I you are familiar with Farsi). They are as the sites below:
http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa35309

http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/id22459

Answer (score 2):

In regard to the clarification about the history of Twelver Shia branch, it could be profitable to know that there are various viewpoint regarding the appearance of Shia.

For instance:

> **Imamiah Shia believe that the initial seed of Shiite has made by
> Allah.**
>
> (Shia Shenasi wa pasokh be Shobahat)
>
> ر.ک: رضوانى‏، على اصغر، شیعه شناسى و پاسخ به شبهات، ج ‏1، ص 39 – 41،
> تهران، نشر مشعر، چاپ دوم، 1384ش
>
> **and the Prophet (blessings of Allah be upon him and his family ) .   Helped that during the period of his prophetic mission.**
>
> (Al-Shia fel Islam, page21) /  طباطبائى‏، سیدمحمد حسین، الشیعة فی الإسلام، ص 21، بیروت، بیت الکاتب‏،
> چاپ اول،  1999م‏؛ سبحانی، جعفر، الأضواء على عقائد الشیعة الإمامیة، ص:
> 17 – 18، قم، مؤسسه امام صادق(ع)؛ حکیم،  سید محمد باقر،

Therefore it has been resulted at the era of Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) and that’s why some people at the time of the Prophet (SAWW) were famous as this name, Such as: Salman-e-Farsi, Abuzar-Qafari, and Meqdad-ibn-Aswad.

- A group of Sahabah at the time of the Prophet (SAWW) made their belief to him (Imam Ali (a.s.)) by hearing the verses and traditions
  Regarding the order of Imamate and Welayah of Imam Ali (peace be upon
  him) . That group became famous as Shia since that time. Ibn Khaldun Says: A group of the Sahabah were Shia of Imam Ali (a.s.) and knew him as a
  Person who was more competent in compare with others for the caliphate
  (Succession).

According to some narrations, Prophet Muhammad (صلی الله علیه و آله و سلم ) gave the title of Shia to the followers of  Amir-al-Momenin Ali (a.s.), like:

> «وَ الَّذِی نَفْسِی بِیَدِهِ، إِنَّ هَذَا وَ شِیعَتَهُ لَهُمُ
> الْفَائِزُونَ یَوْمَ الْقِیَامَة»
>
> (I swear) I my Allah that my life is in his hands that this (Imam-Ali)
> and his followers will be saved at the doomsday.
>
> ابن عقده کوفی، احمد بن محمد، فضائل أمیر المؤمنین(ع)، محقق، حرز الدین،
> عبد الرزاق محمد حسین، ص 219، قم، دلیل ما، چاپ اول، 1424ق؛ شیخ طوسی،
> محمد بن حسن‏، الأمالی، ص 251، قم، دار الثقافة، چاپ اول، 1414ق.

**Of course there are other viewpoints regarding the appearance of Shiite such as:**

- A group believe that Shiite is related to the end of the period of
  Othman caliphate …
- A group believe that Shiite has appeared at the day of Fetnatul-Daar
  (the day of the murder of 3rd caliph )
- A group believe that Shiite appeared after the issue of Hakamiah to
  martyrdom of Imam Ali (a.s.)
- A group believe that the start of the appearance of Shiite is related
  to the event of Karbala and the martyrdom of Imam Hussain.

With respect to your last question which inquired “Does this claim that Safavid Empire in Persia was the main reason for the Twelver Shi'ism becoming the mainstream Shia sect has anything to do with reality?”

It could be profitable to point that appearance of a religion (Mazhab) is not feasible to be occurred at once, actually this is a matter which is done gradually. So we cannot term it related to any specific period such as Safaviah (Safavid) . On the whole, the events which occurred during ten centuries, could be considered as the main reason of the appearance of Shia Islam in Iran.

---

**References:**

- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=227248)
- [www.aviny.com](http://www.aviny.com/shobhe/eteghadi/117.aspx://)

Comment: Poorly formatted this is.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, you are right, I edited it just now (to some extent). I hope it be better than before. Good luck.